# Получить разницу между двумя датами в днях jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть две даты в формате 20.02.1992, как между ними посчитать разницу в днях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно сконвертировать даты в стандартный формат и вычислить разницу между датами:

```js
let date1 = new Date(convert_date_format('20.02.1992'));
let date2 = new Date(convert_date_format('28.02.1992'));
let date_diff = new Date(date2 - date1);
console.log(date_diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);

function convert_date_format(date_string) {
  let date = date_string.split('.', 3);
  return date[1] + '/' + date[0] + '/' + date[2];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема была с конвертацией :(